# Remove rows out of a specific year range, without using for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, grouping

I am looking for a way to omit the rows which are not between two specific values, without using `for` loop. All rows in year column are between 1999 and 2002, however some of them do not include all years between these two dates. You can see the initial data as follows:

```
a <- data.frame(year = c(2000:2002,1999:2002,1999:2002,1999:2001), 
                id=c(4,6,2,1,3,5,7,4,2,0,-1,-3,4,3))

   year id
1  2000  4
2  2001  6
3  2002  2
4  1999  1
5  2000  3
6  2001  5
7  2002  7
8  1999  4
9  2000  2
10 2001  0
11 2002 -1
12 1999 -3
13 2000  4
14 2001  3
```

Processed dataset should only include consecutive rows between 1999:2002. The following `data.frame` is exactly what I need:

```
  year id
1 1999  1
2 2000  3
3 2001  5
4 2002  7
5 1999  4
6 2000  2
7 2001  0
8 2002 -1
```

When I execute the following `for` loop, I get previous `data.frame` without any problem:

```
for(i in 1:which(a$year == 2002)[length(which(a$year == 2002))]){
  if(a[i,1] == 1999 & a[i+3,1] == 2002){
    b <- a[i:(i+3),]
  }else{next}

  if(!exists("d")){
    d <- b
  }else{
    d <- rbind(d,b)
  }
}
```

However, I have more than 1 million rows and I need to do this process without using `for` loop. Is there any faster way for that?

Comment: Are there other columns in the data that ensure the row order? It seems like your data happen to be in order based on some type of grouping and that that grouping is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. First we create groups of consecutive numbers, then we join with the full date range, then we filter if any group is not full. If you already have a grouping variable, this can be cut down a lot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(year = c(2000:2002,1999:2002,1999:2002,1999:2001), 
                id=c(4,6,2,1,3,5,7,4,2,0,-1,-3,4,3))

df %>% 
  mutate(groups = cumsum(c(0,diff(year)!=1))) %>% 
  nest(-groups) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, .f = ~full_join(.x, data_frame(year = 1999:2002), by = "year")),
         drop = map_lgl(data, ~any(is.na(.x$id)))) %>%
  filter(drop == FALSE) %>% 
  unnest() %>%
  select(-c(groups, drop))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>    year    id
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1  1999     1
#> 2  2000     3
#> 3  2001     5
#> 4  2002     7
#> 5  1999     4
#> 6  2000     2
#> 7  2001     0
#> 8  2002    -1
```

Created on 2018-08-31 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that can do this automatically.

First, install the package called `dplyr` or `tidyverse` with command `install.packages("dplyr")` or `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

Then, load the package with `library(dplyr)`.

Then, use the `filter` function: `a_filtered = filter(a, year >=1999 & year < 2002)`.

This should be fast even there are many rows.

Comment: This would not change the data set above as all the rows' year are between 1999 and 2002. The OP is looking to keep only rows that come in groupings of 1999, 2000, 2001 and 2002. Only rows 4 through 11 do that.

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this by creating a grouping column based on the logical expression checking the 'year' 1999, then `filter` by checking the `first` 'year' as '1999', `last` as '2002' and `if` `all` the 'year' in between are present for the particular 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(year == 1999)) %>%
  filter(dplyr::first(year) == 1999, 
         dplyr::last(year) == 2002, 
         all(1999:2002 %in% year)) %>%
  ungroup %>% # in case to remove the 'grp'
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#   year    id
#  <int> <dbl>
#1  1999     1
#2  2000     3
#3  2001     5
#4  2002     7
#5  1999     4
#6  2000     2
#7  2001     0
#8  2002    -1
```